# AD Authentication in Power BI

Tags: authentication, active-directory, powerbi

Is it possible to implement AD Authentication in PowerBI. If yes, how to do AD Authentication for PowerBI.
I need to know the step. And if its not possible, then what are the Alternative for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication in Power BI is done using Azure Active Directory (AAD).  You can read about it here.  There are techniques for sync'ing your AD with AAD.

Here's how to create an App in Azure Active Directory: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn877542.aspx

Here's a starting point for the sync feature I mentioned:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2014/09/16/azure-active-directory-sync-is-now-ga.aspx